# python 2.7 not sending host headers to nginx

Tags: python

I am declaring my headers:

```
headers = {
    "Host": "somehost.somedomain.com",
    "Authorization": "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode(authorization)
}
```

And then calling my url:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host_name, 443, timeout=timeout, context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
conn.timeout = timeout
conn.request("GET", url, "", headers)
```

The authorization works, but in my nginx logs I see the server_name as blank

```
{ "@timestamp": "2019-01-21T10:32:40+00:00", "client": "172.19.0.1", "server_name": "_", "server_port": "443",
```

If I do a curl -H it works

```
curl -H "Host: somehost.somedomain.com"
{ "@timestamp": "2019-01-21T10:32:21+00:00", "client": "172.19.0.1", "server_name": "somehost.somedomain.com", "server_port": "443",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you're losing the `Host` header at some other point than the Python code, which looks right and does the right thing for me

fixing a couple of issues and turning this into a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
from base64 import b64encode
from httplib import HTTPSConnection
import ssl

authorization = b"user:pass"
headers = {
    "Host": "somehost.somedomain.com",
    "Authorization": "Basic %s" % b64encode(authorization)
}

conn = HTTPSConnection(
    'www.google.com', 443, timeout=30,
    context=ssl._create_unverified_context())

conn.set_debuglevel(1)

conn.request("GET", "/", None, headers)
resp = conn.getresponse()
print resp.status, resp.reason
conn.close()
```

Note: I took the opportunity of replacing the `body` param to `request` with `None`  which is what it recognizes — you were passing an empty string, which is an empty body rather than no body.

The `set_debuglevel` causes the library to dump protocol level output to the console while running, so it produces output like:

```
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: somehost.somedomain.com\r\nAuthorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n'
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
header: Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
header: Content-Length: 1561
header: Date: Mon, 21 Jan 2019 11:50:28 GMT
header: Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
404 Not Found
```

note that this response is coming back from Google, which obviously fails hence the `404 Not Found` coming back.

you can see from the `send:` line that it's sending an appropriate `Host` Header.